# Gizmos are not showing up on objects anymore

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, particles

I am building a AR app in unity that includes clouds and I keep receiving this error:
transform.localPosition assign attempt for 'Cloud_System (1)' is not valid. Input localPosition is { NaN, NaN, NaN }.
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
could anyone explain what this error means and what I could do to fix this, the only reason I can think way this is happening is because the potions for the cloud particles are really far up.

[image]

Comment: Some unity forums suggests that you descale your object to something like 1000 instead of 1.5e+7  and others say its a bug with unity physics